# remote process run through ssh gets killed if UI is closed

Tags: ssh, scripting, python, background-process, nohup

I have written a script which essentially does 2 things:

- Runs a UI for listening to the actual program running on the server
- remotely run the program on the server

All goes well, the UI starts, then the program is run on the server. But as soon as I close the UI the remote process gets killed.

Relevant portions of the script:

```
ui_pid = subprocess.check_output('/home/user/git/sim_ui.sh', shell=True)
command = 'ssh user@server "bash -c \'cd program_dir/ && echo \"running program >> log.out && ./program.sh >> log.out\'"'
print command                                                                                       
os.system(command)
```

*sim_ui.sh*:

```
nohup ui_binary args > ui_out.txt &
```

I also am unable to find out what killed the process on the server i.e. signal which terminated the process and where it originated from.

**Edit:**
When I add `screen -dm` before `bash -c` it works perfectly.

Comment: I assume there is some kind of communication between the UI and the program running on the server?

Comment: @koalo Yes. But not of the kind where the remote program terminates upon closing the UI. When I add `screen -dm` before `bash -c` everything works perfectly.

Comment: I could not understand, what did happen when run `nohup ui_binary args > ui_out.txt &`?